# Solving an equation involving a matrix and a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have to solve the following equation for x:$$ \sum_{k} (x'A_kx - 1)(A_kx)=0$$ 
$A_k$ is a matrix and $x$ is a vector. Can anyone give me some suggestion on how to solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: x = 0 is a solution.

Comment: So the result is $\vec 0$, not $0$ right?

Comment: It is a vector yes. There may be other more interesting solutions though. You may be able to find a non-zero vector common to all the null spaces of the $A_k$ for example. There may also be other vectors outside the null spaces of the $A_k$

Comment: Thank you Paul. Is there a name of the method that finds "a non-zero vector common to all the null spaces" of the matrix? I would like to learn more about this method.

Comment: No method, just solve each equation $A_{k}x=0$ using row reduction and see if there is a common solution to each equation.

Comment: okay I will try this out. Thanks!